# Cannot get values from textboxes in templateField inside of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, templatefield

Sorry about the code earlier. Could anyone please help?
I have a gridview `GridView1` which is populated on `PageLoad()` by importing from Excel sheet that has three columns:

1. Date
2. Customers
3. PayingBookNoOrDD

The sheet has five rows. Users can edit the data in textboxes on the page (markup below). After editing, when the user clicks on the submit button, I need to get these new values from all the textboxes and update the same Excel sheet from where the `GridView` was populated.

I created three string arrays: `dateArray`, `custArray`, and `payingInBookArray` to store these new values. But when I run the application all three arrays are empty.

**Markup:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Date,Customers,PayingInBookNoOrDD" >
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>Date</HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>Customers</HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCustomers" Text='<%# Bind("Customers") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>PayingInBookNoOrDD</HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPayingInBookNoOrDD" Text='<%# Bind("PayingInBookNoOrDD") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="txtSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="txtSubmit_Click" />
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Month1$B2:D5]";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

    conn.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectQuery, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    conn.Close();
    da.Dispose();
    conn.Dispose();
}

protected void txtSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IList<string> DateArray = new List<string>();
    IList<string> custArray = new List<string>();
    IList<string> payInBookArray = new List<string>();

    foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        TextBox lblDate = (TextBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("txtDate");
        DateArray.Add(lblDate.Text);

        TextBox lblCustomers = (TextBox)gr.Cells[1].FindControl("txtCustomers");
        custArray.Add(lblCustomers.Text);

        TextBox lblPayInBookNo = (TextBox)gr.Cells[2].FindControl("txtPayingInBookNoOrDD");
        payInBookArray.Add(lblPayInBookNo.Text);
    }

    ExportToExcel(DateArray.ToArray(), custArray.ToArray(), payInBookArray.ToArray()); 

}
```

Please let me know if anyone has a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clean-up your code examples...way too much to edit

Comment: Hi CAbbott, Sorry I am new to this site. I tried to edit the question but it got even more messier. Please give me a few minutes and I will fix it.

Comment: Dont call your buttons `txtSubmit` or anything prefacing a `txt` if its really a button `btn`, it can be very misleading.  You also should wrap your connection object using the `using` statement, that way you don't have to call `.dispose()` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Add a postback check on your Page_Load event. I can't see anything wrong with your btn_Submit code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!this.IsPostBack){
         string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Month1$B2:D5]";
         OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
         conn.Open();
         OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectQuery, conn);
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         da.Fill(ds);
         GridView1.DataSource = ds;
         GridView1.DataBind();
         conn.Close();
         da.Dispose();
         conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would change your `txtSubmit_Click` function to this:

```
protected void txtSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IList<string> DateArray = new List<string>();
    IList<string> custArray = new List<string>();
    IList<string> payInBookArray = new List<string>();

    foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        TextBox lblDate = (TextBox)gr.FindControl("txtDate");
        DateArray.Add(lblDate.Text);

        TextBox lblCustomers = (TextBox)gr.FindControl("txtCustomers");
        custArray.Add(lblCustomers.Text);

        TextBox lblPayInBookNo = (TextBox)gr.FindControl("txtPayingInBookNoOrDD");
        payInBookArray.Add(lblPayInBookNo.Text);
    }

    ExportToExcel(DateArray.ToArray(), custArray.ToArray(), payInBookArray.ToArray()); 

}
```

I've always had problems trying to directly access values in the `.Cells` collection. What happens when you call `.FindControl` on the row itself?

As others have said, it's worth thinking about new names for your HTML fields and your variables. It seems trivial now to have `DateArray` of type `IList`, but it briefly threw me for a loop to see `DateArray.ToArray()`. Naming conventions and other small source code changes won't take you a lot of time to fix now, but will save you plenty of time later when you have to revisit this code after weeks or months of working on other projects.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub txtNombres_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Session("FiltroNombres") = DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the following method to collect the value

foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)

{

string date= ((TextBox)gr.FindControl("txtDate")).text;

}